# Ruby on Rails Helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, helper

Are rails helpers the same as methods. Aren't they just custom to the views?

I know that methods can be made within the controllers but the way I have been understanding  that helpers are custom made methods that can be called upon and used within the views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Helpers are functions defined in the helpers directory, and they are different from the controller actions.

Let's say, you are creating a form in a view, and you want this form to have a drop down menu to all countries in the world, then you would define a helper inside helpers directory that contains all the countries and then call this helper inside your view, instead of listing the actual countries in your view.

Controller actions on the other hand are different, they are also functions like helpers, but they perform operations like create a new record in the database, or delete a record, and so on.

Read through http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html for a deeper understanding.